# Is it possible to forward SMS messages to a non Twilio number and retain the original FROM?

Tags: twilio

I have a requirement that when a customer sends a specific message to our Twilio long code number we need to record the message and forward it to a 3rd party.  The 3rd party has a short code that handles that type of message.

I looked into redirection, but looks like its aimed at API's.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/redirect

The message would need to have the original body and FROM phone number.  From poking around the website, I don't think this is possible.  Just posting in case there are some alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you need to forward received message with from number to 3rd party non twilio number. For this you need to send a message from sms_receiver url script.

Try below code :

```
<?php

$from_number = +1234567890 // valid sms enabled twilio number from your account
$to_number = +19876543210 // number to whom sms had to be forwarded
$message = "From : ".$_REQUEST["From"]."\n\nBody : ".$_REQUEST["Body"];

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
echo '<Response>';
echo '<Message to="'.$to_number.' from="'.$from_number.'"">';
echo $message;
echo '</Message>';
echo '</Response>';

?>
```